# When developing a MVC project, is the the toolbox really useful?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm a noobie when it comes to VS, specifically VS 2010.  I'm trying to learn MVC 2.0.  If you're developing a pure MVC project, it seems like most of the toolbox is not useful.  Shouldn't the IDE hide controls that aren't useful?  Specifically, I'm looking at the AJAX extensions like Timer and UpdatePanel, but it seems like a lot controls more would require postback.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6c63317805.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6c63317805.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

The ASP.NET WebForms controls in the Toolbox are pretty useless during ASP.NET MVC development. While it may be pinned by default, you can choose to hide it from the 'View' menu.

Comment: is there a way to tell if a control is a webform control?